# Javascript union of two object

Tags: javascript, object, properties, union

I have one object:

```
Object { name: " ", email: " " }
```

and another:

```
Object { name: Array[x], email: Array[y]}
```

and I want union like:

```
Object { name: {" ", Array[x]}, email: {" ", Array[y]} }
```

Comment: You mean arrays right? `Object { name: [" ", Array[x]], email: [" ", Array[y]] }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) to achieve your desire.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join the same keys into arrays like this:

```
Object { name: [" ", Array[x]], email: [" ", Array[y]] }
```

Try looping through each object and push the value:

```
var obj3 = {name:[],email:[]};

for(var i in obj1) {
    obj3[i].push(obj1[i]);
}

for(var i in obj2) {
    obj3[i].push(obj2[i]);
}
```